# Magit forge: updating the branch of a pull request

Tags: magit

Does forge support updating the branch of a PR?

Suppose that I checked out a PR branch with `b y`, and afterwards there were additional commits into this PR.

It seems that I cannot pull these new commits with `magit-pull`, because `pushRemote` is not set, and upstream is set to `master`.

The only way I see to update the branch is to delete the PR's branch, and then check it out again with `b y`. Am I right on this one? Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to begin by fetching everything using <kbd>f a</kbd>.

> `pushRemote` is not set

The push remote *is* configured. Check the rebase popup it; it should show that this is the case.

> Is there a more convenient way to do this?

What I do is to first fetch everything and then do either a hard-reset, if I did not change anything locally, or I rebase onto push target otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean, hard-reset, and then choose the branch from the presented list? When I create a PR branch, it will be named "pr-XXX". I don't know the remote, and the remote branch, so I cannot choose it from the list presented at reset.

Comment: Yes. I never have that problem after <kbd>l b</kbd>. There I can see what the appropriate branch is. Otherwise it is inconvenient, but at least you can determine the value by visiting the pr discussion from the pr list where that information is being displayed.

Comment: Actually, this solution has approximately the same complexity as delete-branch-and-re-create-it. But I'll accept the answer nonetheless.